# How to display date string with only day and month based on culture?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datetime, windows-phone-7.1, datetime-format

I need to display some dates on windows phone with day and month only.

For example, January 1st, for American users I want the text to be '1/31' and for UK users I want it to be '31/1'.

What's the easiest way to achieve something like this?

**UPDATE:**
My app will be available in a lot of countries. Do I have to specify each culture to get what I want?

For example,

```
de-DE Culture                         01.10
en-US Culture                         10/1
es-ES Culture                         01/10
fr-FR Culture                         01/10
```

The left column contains some countries my app will support, the right column is how I want my date text to be.

Is there any generic way I can achieve this?

Comment: Can't you specify CultureInfo when you parse a DateTime ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, that question is particularly interesting! I didn't found some obvious solution, so here it goes:

```
    char[] trimmer = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.DateSeparator.ToCharArray();
    string dateStr = date.ToString("d").Replace(date.ToString("yyyy"), string.Empty).Trim(trimmer);
```

If you can't use `DateTimeFormatInfo`, then following code should do the trick:

```
string tmp = date.ToString("d").Replace(date.ToString("yyyy"), string.Empty);
char last = tmp[tmp.Length - 1];
char[] trimmer = char.IsDigit(last) ? new char[] { tmp[0] } : new char[] { last };
string dateStr = tmp.Trim(trimmer);
```

As [@ken2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870604/ken2k) correctly mentioned, this solution is also flawed (and much more than I actually expected). Here is the complere test suite ([compile as console application](http://ideone.com/jhtmQ)):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);

        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
        {
            string tmp = date.ToString("d", culture).Replace(date.ToString("yyyy", culture), string.Empty);
            char last = tmp[tmp.Length - 1];
            char[] trimmer = char.IsDigit(last) ? new char[] { tmp[0] } : new char[] { last };
            string dateStr = tmp.Trim(trimmer);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,12}, {1,15} => {2,10}", culture.IetfLanguageTag, date.ToString("d", culture), dateStr));
        }

        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit..");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Further optimization is possible (at least in full framework), however it's becoming rather complex (limited framework of a Windows Phone adds complexity also) and it's not clear if such date representation will make sense in some cultures. For example in some cultures date part separator is a two-char sequence:

> hu-HU,   2012. 08. 14. =>     08. 14

does `08. 14` actually look good? Or should it be `08. 14.`? I'm not sure. If I were you, and I really want to handle maximum amount of cultures, I would just stick with standard "d" format specifier.

Comment: +1 I like your answer! However I couldn't use the trimmer function as DateSeparator is not supported in wp7. :( But it's easy to fix I can just use a Substring function to get rid of the last char. If I don't receive any better answers in a few hours I am happy to accept yours. :)

Comment: You shouldn't remove last char, since year can come before month (in Japan, for example). See updated answer.

Comment: You shouldn't work on formated dates using string functions such as `Replace`, `Trim`...etc. There are lots of different culture formats, and you can't take all cases into account. For example, your code assumes `date.ToString("d")` always contains the year in the `yyyy` form for all cultures, which is not true (test `"kn-IN"` for example).

Comment: @ken2k I know that fact (that's why this question is interesting), however there is no perfect solution. The `m` format produces different output from desired, so it's just a metter of a reasonably generic solution. Special culture cases can be treated separately if necessary.

Comment: @ken2k Thanks for clarifying this... Can you please tell me where I can find a full list of countries with their own datetime strings so I can write a functoin to filter them out?

Comment: @Jessica you can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx method to get all available cultures.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin I tried to use GetCultures but it's not available in windows phone. :(

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Thank you so much for this, really appreciate it. I have actually tested your code with every single country that's available in wp7 and turned out they all formatted quite well except a couple of them having the year "/12" at the end. But I think I can live with it. :)

Comment: So, then *reasonably generic solution* is working, but be careful with it! :)

Answer (score 5):

```
// 13 August
string americanDate = theDate.ToString("m", new CultureInfo("en-us"));

// August 13
string ukDate = theDate.ToString("m", new CultureInfo("en-gb"));
```

For full list of available formats, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx).

EDIT:

In your app, don't manually specify a `CultureInfo` instance: use the default culture for `DateTime.ToString`, which is the culture of the executing thread.

So your code becomes:

```
string cultureSpecificDate = theDate.ToString("m");
```

where `"m"` is a date format you choose in the list of available formats. The one you want doesn't appear to be a standard one provided by the [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1at0z4ew) class. Couldn't you choose a supported pattern in the list below?

```
/*
This code produces the following output.

FORMAT  en-US EXAMPLE
CHAR    VALUE OF ASSOCIATED PROPERTY, IF ANY

  d     1/3/2002
        M/d/yyyy (ShortDatePattern)

  D     Thursday, January 03, 2002
        dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy (LongDatePattern)

  f     Thursday, January 03, 2002 12:00 AM

  F     Thursday, January 03, 2002 12:00:00 AM
        dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt (FullDateTimePattern)

  g     1/3/2002 12:00 AM

  G     1/3/2002 12:00:00 AM

  m     January 03
        MMMM dd (MonthDayPattern)

  M     January 03
        MMMM dd (MonthDayPattern)

  o     2002-01-03T00:00:00.0000000

  r     Thu, 03 Jan 2002 00:00:00 GMT
        ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT' (RFC1123Pattern)

  R     Thu, 03 Jan 2002 00:00:00 GMT
        ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT' (RFC1123Pattern)

  s     2002-01-03T00:00:00
        yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss (SortableDateTimePattern)

  t     12:00 AM
        h:mm tt (ShortTimePattern)

  T     12:00:00 AM
        h:mm:ss tt (LongTimePattern)

  u     2002-01-03 00:00:00Z
        yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z' (UniversalSortableDateTimePattern)

  U     Thursday, January 03, 2002 8:00:00 AM

  y     January, 2002
        MMMM, yyyy (YearMonthPattern)

  Y     January, 2002
        MMMM, yyyy (YearMonthPattern)

*/
```

Comment: @Jessica Well, if you don't choose a standard pattern, I'm not sure there is an actual general solution for your issue (expect having to write specific code for each supported culture). The examples you gave (de, en, es, fr) _could_ be defined as the [`ShortDatePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern) pattern without the year, but for other more "exotic" cultures, what would be the expected result? Only a well-defined pattern (i.e. one in the above list) can ensure the output for all cultures.